# How to conditionally apply classNames (JIT) with Tailwind and React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following object map:

```
const stylesMap = {
  level: {
    1: "text-5xl",
    ...
  },
};
```

In my component I have:

```
const ComponentExample = (props) => {
  const { level } = props;
  return (
    <h1 className={classNames(stylesMap.level[level ?? stylesMap.level[1]])}>
      Test
    </h1>
  );
};
```

As a test I have made `level: null` expecting the values `"text-5xl"` to be part of the classNames list but I don't see it. I'm simply trying to set default values if the props are null.

I even add `safelist: ["text-5xl"]` in the tailwindcss config but that didn't work even though its already picked up in `stylesMap` Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what happened. I was passing the actual value instead of the key.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

```
const ComponentExample = (props) => {
  const { level } = props;
  return (
    <h1 className={classNames(stylesMap.level[level ?? 1])}>
      Test
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clsx` library. It's used for applying classNames conditionally.

```
<h1 className={clsx({[stylesMap.level[1]: level]})}>
   Test
</h1>
```

Ex:

```
const menuStyle = clsx({
        [classes.root] : true, //always applies
        [classes.menuOpen] : open //only when open === true
    })
```

For your reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary condition check for this.

```js
const ComponentExample = (props) => {
  const { level } = props;
  return (
    <h1 className={level === null ? "text-5xl" : null}>
      Test
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way

```
const ComponentExample = (props) => {
  const { level } = props;
  return (
    <h1
      className={
        stylesMap?.level && stylesMap?.level[1]
          ? stylesMap.level[1]
          : 'text-5xl'
      }
    >
      Test
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition = condition to check for deciding which className to give

trueValue = the className to give in case the condition is true

falseValue = the className to give in case the condition is false

```
<h1 className={condition ? trueValue : falseValue}>
     Test
</h1>
```